# file upload to database in liferay

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

Hey guys i am new to liferay and have urgent requirment of uploading a file(excel if possible)  and making database entries.

Have gathered info that jsp page should contain

```
<aui:form action="<%=actionURL%>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="<%=Constants.IMPORT_ACTION %>" >
    <div class="manage-main" style="padding-top: 20px;">
        <table>`

            <tr>
                <td class="lbl"><liferay-ui:message key="select-file-to-upload" /></td>
                <td><input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" size="40" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    <aui:button type="submit" value="upload" name="upload" cssClass="topSpace"/>
</aui:form>
```

---

**java code**

```
// you can directly cast from renderRequest to portletRequest.    
UploadPortletRequest upreq = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(portletRequest);
CsvReader csv =getCSV(upreq);
```

Please provide some steps which could be easily understood as i have little time to explore.

Comment: so what do you want to do exactly? either upload and store a file in the database or upload and store the file as liferay does in its `Document & Media Library` portlet? Thanks

Comment: to upload and store columns data in database.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the JSF2 and Primefaces3 reference portlets for the [Liferay Faces bridge](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/demos). They contain example code on how to do a file upload. That will get you an actual reference to a file in your backing bean code. Then it just depends on what you actually want to do with that file and what you mean by 'making database entries'.

You can read in the file and then use something like JDBC or Hibernate to persist information to the database.

If you just need to store the actual file itself, then you can use something like the Liferay [DLAppLocalServiceUtil](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLAppLocalServiceUtil.html) to store the file inside of the Liferay media gallery.